# How many solutions does the equation $2i+j+3k=l$ have in nonnegative integers?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $i,j,k$ be nonnegative integers and $l$ be a positive integer.

**How many solutions does the equation $2i+j+3k=l$ have?**

For low enough $l$, I can easily find the number of solutions, but is there a general formula which gives, for arbitrary $l$, the number of solutions? Maybe in some combinatorial way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is a recurrence relation describing this problem. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) for details.

**Correction:**

Following the description in the link you are asking for what they denote by $p_1(l)+p_2(l)+p_3(l)$, namely the total number of partitions of $l$ you can make with each term at most equal to $3$. Given $(i,j,k)$ in your equation above we have a partition of $2i+j+3k=l$ given as
$$
\overbrace{1+1+...+1}^{j\text{ times}}+\overbrace{2+2+...+2}^{i\text{ times}}+\overbrace{3+3+...+3}^{k\text{ times}}=l
$$
and we have to add $p_1+p_2+p_3$ since these count the partitions in which the largest part equals $1, 2$ and $3$ respectively, so in effect $p_1$ counts solutions to your equation with $i=k=0$, $p_2$ counts solutions with $i\neq 0$ but $k=0$, and finally $p_3$ counts solutions with $k\neq 0$. So together they give all solutions.

This can be computed recursively for different values of $l$ by applying the recurrence $p_k(n)=p_k(n-k)+p_{k-1}(n-1)$ which leads to the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c:c:c:c:c|c|}
\hline
l&p_0(l)&p_1(l)&p_2(l)&p_3(l)&p_1+p_2+p_3\\
\hline
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
\hdashline
1&0&1&0&0&1\\
\hdashline
2&0&1&1&0&2\\
\hdashline
3&0&1&1&1&3\\
\hdashline
4&0&1&2&1&4\\
\hdashline
5&0&1&2&2&5\\
\hdashline
6&0&1&3&3&7\\
\hdashline
7&0&1&3&4&8\\
\hdashline
8&0&1&4&5&10\\
\hdashline
9&0&1&4&7&12\\
\hdashline
10&0&1&5&8&14\\
\hdashline
11&0&1&5&10&16\\
\hdashline
12&0&1&6&12&19\\
\hdashline
13&0&1&6&14&21\\
\hdashline
14&0&1&7&16&24\\
\hdashline
15&0&1&7&19&27\\
\hdashline
16&0&1&8&21&30\\
\hdashline
17&0&1&8&24&33\\
\hdashline
18&0&1&9&27&37\\
\hdashline
19&0&1&9&30&40\\
\hdashline
20&0&1&10&33&44\\
\hdashline
21&0&1&10&37&48\\
\hdashline
22&0&1&11&40&52\\
\hdashline
23&0&1&11&44&56\\
\hdashline
24&0&1&12&48&61\\
\hdashline
25&0&1&12&52&65\\
\hdashline
26&0&1&13&56&70\\
\hdashline
27&0&1&13&61&75\\
\hdashline
28&0&1&14&65&80\\
\hdashline
29&0&1&14&70&85\\
\hdashline
30&0&1&15&75&91\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
So the figures you are asking for is the list starting as follows: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 37, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 61, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 91, 96, 102, 108, 114, 120, 127, 133, 140, 147, 154, 161, 169, ... Searching for this in OEIS.org reveals that this is a [known sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%2C%207%2C%208%2C%2010%2C%2012%2C%2014%2C%2016%2C%2019%2C%2021%2C%2024%2C%2027%2C%2030%2C%2033%2C%2037%2C%2040&sort=&language=english&go=Search). It also says something there regarding formulas for those figures, but I have not read that more closely.

Comment: Sorry - something is not right about my table yet - I will try to fix it and edit ...

Comment: Now it should be OK!

Comment: thanks a lot for this nice answer!